# SameSite=None not working for Apache 2.2.15 and Tomcat 6

Tags: apache, tomcat6

I have Apache 2.2.15 with tomcat 6, and I am trying to set the following command in Apache:

```
Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None
```

this is not working. I would really appreciate if any advice and help, since then the iFrame capability is broken.

Answer (score 0):

That command is so far off it's hard to tell what your intent was.

If you're trying to modify a cookie, don't you want `Header edit`... here? 
If you're actually trying to set a new cookie, you're missing the cookie name and value.

https://github.com/covener/apache-samesite/blob/master/samesite-global.conf

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie "^(?!.*(\s+|;)(?i)SameSite=)(.*)" "$0; SameSite=None; Secure" env=!SAMESITE_SKIP
Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie "^(?!.*(\s+|;)(?i)SameSite=)(.*)" "$0; SameSite=None; Secure" env=!SAMESITE_SKIP
Header always edit Set-Cookie "(.*(\s+|;)(?i)Secure(\s+|;).*) Secure$" "$1" env=!SAMESITE_SKIP
Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie "(.*(\s+|;)(?i)Secure(\s+|;).*) Secure$" "$1" env=!SAMESITE_SKIP
```

Comment: Thanks Covener for the reply. Will the above command work for Apache 2.2.15 version?

I am in my  "xxx.force.com" site, trying to punchout to another site yyy.blah.com by iFrame. With the samesite flags enabled (v80 flags update) the iFrame punchout is not happening. 

Trying to set the following command in Apache by reading some blogs and is not working, dont see SameSite=None set in the Response Header.

"Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None"

Comment: They ought to.  "header set" version seems futile.

Comment: I put the above 4 commands towards the end of file in httpd.conf, when I iframe to other domain i dont see the cookie set to SameSite=None, Secure in the Network tab under Response header. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: The cookie set by the 'other domain' needs to be changed. Are you configuring the right server?

Comment: I am configuring to correct servers, but after doing more analysis here is what I found and need some help.
We have site A (aaa.com), (AAASession cookie is set) , after login in site A we redirect to another Site B (bbb.bom). Given its redirect the AAASession is not passed on redirect, and from Site B i do iFrame to Site C (ccc.com) and Site C required AAASession to sucessfully login.
With SameSite default, i can see the AAASession on Site A/Site C, whereas with SameSite Enabled (Chrome Update fixes going on Feb 17th) i dont see AAASession passed failing to load the iFrame.